# What is the vote effect on the Muse's Unsustainable song?

Tags: voice, effect

I'm talking about the effect on the voice when it says the word "Unsustainable" (around the 1:29 point).  How would you recreate it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like some sort of vocoder - there's probably a preset on the MircoKorg that sounds like that.

If you don't have access to a vocoder or vocoder plugin, then I would suggest the following: record the voice in monotone (no pitch variance). Apply a pitch corrector if you can to force the pitch even smoother. Add a strong amount to ring modulation (for that metallic sound) and a fast LFO (around 10-15Hz as a square wave) to get the roughness. Finally, try a little chorus or flange.

Or find someone who will let you borrow their MicroKorg!